# How to print a view in MVC with out showing printer options screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, printing, printdocument

I have a view which contains few tables and it has some dynamic data.
I need to print this view up on clicking some button.

for ex:

I have following method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeMethod(Someparameter)
{
   if(someclass.somemethod())
   //if the above method returns true I need a print function here to print my view
}
```

I need this print function to be handled in C#,unlike js print().
And the more challenging is I dont want to display the print options to user and user is not aware of printing.
Print function should take configurable printer options and print directly.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
i got the following code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

public void Print()
{
  var doc = new PrintDocument();
  doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\\\deployment-machine-name\\share-name";
  doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
  doc.Print();
}
public void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawString(
"Hello world",
new Font("Arial", 12),
Brushes.Black,
e.MarginBounds.Left,
e.MarginBounds.Top);
}
```

where it takes the printer name and prints the required with out showing printer settings window.
But the problem is I want to print a view(in the above code,it prints a string value).

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Are you wanting to print something to a printer connected to the server? Or are you under the illusion that your server can control (or even know about) a printer on a users computer?

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited the Q,Please check it

Comment: The code you have shown is all server side and will print to a printer on the server (I assume this is must be an intranet app) so the user will know nothing about it (which is why I was unsure what you meant by _I dont want to display the print options to user and user is not aware of printing_ - because they wont). I cant comment on the actual code and if it works - its been a while since I have done anything with `PrintDocument`